# Real-time generation of MSI files

Tags: windows-installer

I need clients to download an MSI with lightly-customized code in order to set a unique registry value.  When they install the MSI, I need to know *their* client ID without them having to type it in.  Specifically because the MSI will be deployed through Group Policy.

During my testing phase, I have hard-coded a registry entry in my Wix installer:

```
<RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="customer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
```

I considered generating a 'standard' MSI and zipping it up with a text file containing the client ID and having the installer read it and write to the registry--but I'd rather have a single file admins can download from their 'web portal' and install.

I have also considered setting up a Windows server with IIS and using a simple web app developed in Visual Studio to accept a ?client_id=blah parameter, then generate the MSI in the background, and then return it in the HTTP response.  While this seems like a great solution, I'm extremely noobish when it comes to .NET development.

Are there any tools or tips there for generating an MSI on-demand with customizations like this?

Ideally, I'd love a 'free' solution, but I realize there might not be any.  I'm open to solutions that involve paying for a service or buying a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would factor your client ID out into a property and then write some custom automation to generate modify a copy of the MSI and then code sign if desired.  The user then downloads the copy of the MSI.

This is a minimal amount of code possible in nearly any language.

Comment: I only got two hours of sleep last night, but I managed to do it.  I built an IHttpHandler that fires off an msbuild process, then grabs the MSI file and returns it.  Only took 24 lines of code.  Might not be the cleanest solution, but I'm fairly astounded that I can take this small bundle of code, stick it on a WIndows Server, and have it build in a matter of seconds... I still have concurrency issues to work out (can only run one build at a time), but it's working.  ;)

Comment: There really shouldn't be any need to build the MSI over and over.  You merely need to transform it.

Comment: The reason is that I want a customer to download *one* file and be able to take that MSI and deploy it through active directory (without transforms), or give the file to a user and have them double-click it to install (transforms from the command line are hard for mere mortals), and I don't want them to have to put in their customer number when they install.  (Customer number is going to be a GUID).   ...unless I am totally misunderstanding how transforms work?

Comment: I'm overloading the word transform in this case.  File.Copy(seed, temp)  Temp.Update()  Download( temp)  All you need to do is update a copy of the MSI.